# How to force position absolute with 100% width to fit into parent div with padding?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, an outer div which is a parent and a child div. The outer div is position relatives with padding 20px for left and right while the child is position absolute with 100% widthg. How can I force the child which is position absolute to be within the parent, ie respecting the padding 20px (inside parent and within the 20px padding)

I've done the example here: http://www.bootply.com/nyGZzTVY8v

I've read about box-sizing but I still don't understand how to implement it correctly. Tried putting it on the box1 class and nothing happen, tried putting on the box2 class and nothing happen also.

thanks in advance.

Additional Note: It has to be responsive ie I do not know the size of the parent div thus the 100% for the child div.

Comment: Nope, not 2 divs in your example.  1 div, 1 p and 1 a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has to be responsive, you could add the the padding as a margin and then use calc for the width:

```
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    left: 0px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0 20px;
    colour: #000;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid thin #06F;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it will be reponsive, I'm just showing part of the whole design.

Comment: do you need to make the second div position absolute?

Comment: Yes I do, as I will need it to stick to a position later and resize itself when the browser resize. Everything is working fine except with that irritating extra space of the child.

I know I can reduce the 100% to something like 95% or so, but I don't think that is the right solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much the calc solve the problem. I thought box-sizing would do the trick. now learn something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Just set `left: 20px;` and `right: 20px;` and remove `width: 100%`

[Live Demo](http://www.bootply.com/QfXswy7K9f)

```
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    border: solid thin #06F;
}
```

or add `left: 20px;` and the [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) `width: calc( 100% - 40px )`

```
.box2 {
position: absolute;
width: calc( 100% - 40px );
padding: 50px 0;
color: #000;
background: #fff;
left: 20px;
border: solid thin #06F;
}
```

[live Demo](http://www.bootply.com/bEE3IHKMVg)

Comment: Left: 0 will fit into the parent box but not respecting the parent padding spacing. I actually wanted the box2 to be inside box1 and respecting the padding. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @StrangeLove use the left and right http://www.bootply.com/QfXswy7K9f or the `calc` function see http://www.bootply.com/bEE3IHKMVg .

Comment: Thank you so much the calc solve the problem. I thought box-sizing would do the trick. now learn something new. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect, try it out. The parent div should have a relative position and the child div could have an absolute position like you want.

```
.box1 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.box2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you use position absolute the div wont be in its parent div.instead you can use position relative with and give it `width:inherit` this will inherit the width of the parent div

Comment: Sorry, but inherit is not working like that. It has no effect if overflow is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem recently and found the solution via setting left & right of child container resolve problem.

If you want child container to have same parent padding e.g padding: 0 10px i.e left & right. Then we need to set left & right of child container with the same value as parent padding.

```
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

To see code-pen
[click here](https://codepen.io/waqas385/pen/poERqzL)