# inline block not sizing to fit its children when positioned absolutely

Tags: css

Here is a fiddle of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/875190we/

```
        <div style = "display:inline-block">
        <span>a</span>
        <span style = "position:relative;top:-1px; font-size:13px">x</span> 3
    </div>
```

I'd like that to say "ax3" (as it would if it was not contained in an absolute element).

I'm using the absolute-ness to position it to the right, and outside of, the grey element. I basically want this element to live to the right of the grey element (which is itself in a larger document structure). But the second I place the inline-block INSIDE of an absolutely positioned element as so, it stops fitting its children.

Comment: is this your requirement ?  http://jsfiddle.net/875190we/3/

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/875190we/4/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set width, replace `initial` by relative size `40px` or with `calc(100%)`.

```html
<body>
    <div style="width:200px;background:grey;position:relative;">hi
        <div style="position:absolute; left:100%; top:0; overflow: visible; width: calc(100%);">
            <div style="display:inline-block"><span>a</span><span style="position:relative;top:-1px; font-size:13px">x</span> 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*(Or you can use `float: left;` instead of `position: absolute;`)*

See :

- [How to force position absolute with 100% width to fit into parent div with padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859952/how-to-force-position-absolute-with-100-width-to-fit-into-parent-div-with-paddi)